# React router link not rendering to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i have done everything but i dnt know why still its not working. am using react and router latest version.Stil am not able to opening my contact page.I have tried everything to solve it but still am not able to do it?
Hello i have done everything but i dnt know why still its not working. am using react and router latest version.Stil am not able to opening my contact page.I have tried everything to solve it but still am not able to do it?

```
    index.js
    
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import New from './components/Navbar';
    import Home from './components/Home';
    import About from './components/About';
    import Services from './components/Services';
    import Name from './components/pages/Name';
    
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,Route,Link,Routes,Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
    
    const App = () => {
    
    return(
    
      <>
          <Router>
          <New/>
            <Switch>
              <Route Path='/' exact component =  {Home} />
              <Route Path='/About' exact component  = {About} />
              <Route Path='/Services' exact component  = {Services}/>
              <Route Path='/Name' exact component  = {Name}/>
              <Route Path='/Home' exact component  = {Home}/>
              
             
          </Switch>
          </Router>
     </>
      )
    
    }
    export default App;
    




 Conatct.jsx
    
    import React from 'react'
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    
    
    function Contact () {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>contact</h1>
                
            </>
        )
    }
    export default Contact;
    




    
    Pages / Name.js (i have import Contact here)
    
    import React from 'react';
    
    import Contact from '../Contact'
    
    export default function Name() {
        return (
            <>
            <Contact />
            </>
        );
    }
    



    
 Navbar.js
    
    import React from 'react';
    import './Navbar.css'
    
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
    import { Button,Container,Navbar,Nav,NavDropdown,NavLink } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import {
      BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,Route,Link,Routes,Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
    
    const New = () => {
        
    
        return (
         <div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className='col-10 mx-auto'>
    
           <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Navbar</NavLink>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-auto mb-lg-2">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/Services">Services</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/About">About</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/Contact">Contact</NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    </div>
    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          
        );
      };
      
    export default New;
```

Comment: can you remove `<New/>` in <Router> and check

Comment: actually its navbar. if i remove this my navbar will be removed.

Comment: there is a chance your contact `h1` is being hidden behind the navbar

Comment: could you explain me more ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, using lowercase only in routes because browser concerto to lowercase

Second thing you need create a link component for react-router, NavLink is only UI element, not a valid like for rect router

should using this

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link